# NSData needs to be updated

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsdata, xml-parsing, nsurl

I am parsing HTML using hpple. so now I want my text to be updated as the user touches the next button. my code looks something like this

```
NSURL *ur = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url.text]];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: ur];
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];     
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//table[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/a/text()"]; // get the page title
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *h3Tag = [element content];  
mi.text = h3Tag;
NSLog(@"%@",h3Tag);
[xpathParser release];
```

so I am kind of a new iPhone application development and fairly new to programming. So over here I think NSData needs to be updated.and yes when the user touches the next button the url also changes. so any help on that would be appreciated

thanks

Tushar

Comment: which text you want to be updated? what its url.text? is it textField? do you have some url associated with your button? please clear these doubts. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply I want to update the mi.text... in my application what is happening is user puts in the url of a web site (in this case i will be putting in the bearmp3.com url which is a music web site) and html parser gets the name of the song...to be honest with u this was a test app to make sure that it updates but unfortunately it didn't...... any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does NSLog print h3Tag correctly?

Comment: yes it does print it our correctly

Comment: everything is working but mi.text is not getting updated? is it in same viewcontroller? have you connected its outlet(if any ) in Interface Builder?

Comment: okay now here is what is happening you have misunderstood the situation.... over here for the first time the text from the web (parsed data) work and is displayed..but now when the user changes the URL (ie url.text)... I want the text to be updated accordingly so for example if first URL is :http://mp3bear.com/?q=akon  and then i update the URL to something else I want the text to change and be parsed.....

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me..i figured it out... i just had to call viewDidload again by [self viewDidload];

Comment: hey please dont do that... You should not call delegate methods like this. What you can do is, if above code is in your viewDidLoad method then put it in some other method and then call that method, instead of calling viewDidLoad. and the code I have written above has less autoreleased objects this will help in reducing memory footprints. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",url.text];

NSURL *ur =[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:tempString];
[tempString release];

NSData *htmlData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:ur];
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
[ur release];
[htmlData release];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//table[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/a/text()"]; // get the page title
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *h3Tag = [element content];  
mi.text = h3Tag;
NSLog(@"%@",h3Tag);
[xpathParser release];
```

try this code.

Thanks.

Comment: on whichever event you want it just write [refereceToYourSearchBarObject resignFirstResponder];

Comment: what is your searchBar object(reference) and on which you are calling. try it with the searchBar argument comming from method [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

Comment: can you please go step by step please..... and yes I have added uisearchbar through interface builder

Comment: have you created its IBOutlet and connected it with your search Bar?

Comment: after doing that i created a method in .m file -(void)dismiss {[searchBar resignFirstResponder];}

Comment: searchBar is name of your outlet right? when you are calling dismiss method? are you using delegate method?- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar use it and do set your searchBar delegate.

Comment: how do i set searchBar to degelegate I clcked on file owners and then drag the delegate + sign to searchBar... is that what you are telling me to do? If yes then that isn't working either for some reason :/

Comment: you can set it in your viewDidLoad as searchBar.delegate=self (I hope you are writing searchBarSearchButtonClicked method in same controller)

Comment: you can post your searchBar adding code(or you have added it via xib?) and the name of searchBar reference and your method for searchBarButtonclick here.

Comment: IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;

Comment: in .m -(void) dismiss: (UISearchBar *)search;

Comment: are you using - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar method? please post viewDidLoad and this method's code in separate question and make this question as answered(if it is,the nsdata one).

Comment: okay here is the link to the other question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5657361/edit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657361/hiding-keyboard-iphone-sdk srry about that

Comment: please see the answer I have posted and make sure everything is in good shape.:)