# Hiding keyboard iphone sdk?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, uiwebview, keyboard, resignfirstresponder

I have a `UISearchBar`. I want the the keyboard to go away as soon as user hits search...i did try `resignFirstResponder` but that didn't work. any help would be appreciated

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Songs", @"Search for songs");


    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"Book_1", @"Book 2", @"Book _ 4", nil];
    self.booksArray = array;
    [array release];
    search.delegate=self;
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

thanks 
TC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure of following things.(I hope you are talking about search Button of keyboard.)

1. You have connected your `IBOutlet` of searchBar with its variable `search`.
2. You are not de-referring search variable anywhere in your code(reassigning it).
3. Your `- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`  method is in same `viewcontroller` as searchBar is in.
4. Please NSLog(@"Search Bar Instace : %@",search); in viewDidLoad method and `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` and verify that both instances are same if not then you are `search` is getting reassigned somewhere in code.
5. Just after `[searchBar resignFirstResponder];` NSLog(@"isFirstResponder : %d",[searchbar isFirstResponder]); and `NSLog(@"Next Responder : %@",[searchBar nextResponder]);`
6. Is `- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`
   method is being called when you tap search Button of keyboard? Make sure there are no keyboard `responder`(like `textField`,`textView` or other `searchBar`) is added behind your `searchBar` may be unintentionally. Please check it through xib also.

Thanks,

Comment: I am kind of embarrassed to say that but it ain't working for some reason I have tried everything I could... I made sure i didn't release search any where and also made sure that searchBar is the firstresponder by going [search isFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

It should work by implementing the respond methods at the delegate object:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Reference: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7148-problem-uisearchbar-navigation-controller.html#post59467